# Symbol for not an ideal

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to write the symbol for not an ideal.
I've been using `\lhd` to represent an ideal so what I want is to put a line through this in the same way `\neq` or `\nless` do for `\eq` and `\less`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `\not\lhd` enough?

Comment: No, I tried that myself but unfortunately that produces the line before the \lhd symbol, so it's "misaligned". I want it to go through the symbol, just like I mentioned the \neq does.

Comment: I'd simply say `$I$ is not an ideal of $R$`. Avoid symbol inflation.

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Is `\lhd` a common symbol for ideals? I use it for normal subgroup.

Comment: @Sigur [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148116/is-lhd-common-notation-for-is-an-ideal-of) is a discussion of it on math.se.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `\centernot` from the same package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{centernot}

\begin{document}

$\centernot{\lhd}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you generate that large image? The one I generated with `standalone` and saved as png with Acrobat looks like crap.

Comment: @JuriRobl Zooming-in in SumatraPDF and capturing the screenshot.

Comment: @stephenmg you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the generated symbol `\not\lhd` or the complete smybol `\nlessclosed`, both of which are from the `MnSymbol` package.
Depending on the symbol packages you're already using, it may change some of the symbols to it's own.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\newcommand{\notlhd}{\nlessclosed}
\begin{document}
$\nlessclosed$ $\notlhd$ $\not\lhd$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to add that `MnSymbol` changes most of the available symbols.

Comment: It depends what he is using at the moment, he may already be using it? But yes, I will add that.